# Can I save my shower floor if I only want to retile my shower walls?

Tags: remodeling

We have a main bathroom that was remodeled around 2014 by the previous owners. We hate the shower tile choice and want to replace but don't mind the pebble floor that is down. The current tile is a mosaic on hardibackerboard. The floor has a liner, mudpack and then tile to a central drain. In checking an access panel the liner comes up behind the backboard by a good 12 inches.
Is it possible to just remove the wall tile and keep the floor or do you I need to scrap everything? This is a roughly 4'x6' walk in shower with shower heads on both end walls.The shower curb is roughly 3.5"x3.5" with a granite slap on top and the shower glass wall mounted to that that.

Comment: Should be able to keep the floor as is.  Sounds like two piece design floor plus wall/s.

Comment: Worry about damaging the liner during removal of the wall tiles.   You can play it by ear.  If the wall tile and thinset can be removed, and the backer board preserved, and if all this can be higher than the top surface of the floor tiles,  maybe you can avoid the liner.

Comment: Thank you. This was my thinking as well. Demo very carefully and if it comes off clean from the backboard then the whole job gets so much easier. Thanks for weighing in.

Answer (score 1):

I have tiled over the tile on the walls in a number of showers and tubs. My own home as well as investment properties.  If the walls are solid, clean them well.
Get a modified thinset. I found some at the local tile store that will hold 1/4 steel plate to a ceiling. (Manager's claim)  But it works for me every time and I have never had an issue. I have found some other properties where this has been done. You can tile over the floor as well. There are parts made to raise the drain to accommodate the new tile

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I think I want to take the tiled walls down and start from scratch. We love the tile pebble floor and down want to lose that. This is. 4x6 shower with his/her shower heads on each wall with a three piece glass door on top of a curb.